# Is it possible to allocate memory within Renderscript?

Tags: android, memory, renderscript

### Background

I'm learning how to use Renderscript, and I found this part in the docs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/advanced.html#mem-allocation

> To support this memory allocation system, there are a set of APIs that
>   allow the Android VM to allocate memory and offer similar
>   functionality to a malloc call.
>
> ...
>
> To better understand how these classes work, it is useful to think of
>   them in relation to a simple malloc call that can look like this:
>
> array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);

### The problem

I'm failing to understand something: What if I want to allocate memory within RS itself?

For example, suppose I need to have a calculation that requires a lot of memory compared to the input and output, can I do it all inside RS itself, instead of from Java?

### What I've tried

I can't even succeed in creating a new array, even if it's in constant size:

```
static int array[1024*1024*100] ; //this is ok

void init() {
   rsDebug("init called. array check:",(int)(*array));
   array[0] = 2; // this is not ok
   rsDebug("init called. array check:",(int)(*array));
}
```

And all I get for this code is this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'D:\android\Sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\llvm-rs-cc.exe'' finished with
> >     non-zero exit value -1073741819

### The questions

1. Is it possible to dynamically allocate memory on RS ? Instead of doing so from Java ?
2. If it's possible, is this memory a part of the heap, or a part of the global, available RAM of the device? Will it be auto-GC-ed when the Renderscript object on Java gets GC-ed ?
3. What about all the static variables that are set inside RS ? Are they a part of the heap?
4. Would all kinds of allocations of RS be automatically freed like on GC , once the Renderscript object on Java gets GC-ed ?

   I ask this because of some weird explanations on the docs.

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: @Olaf I don't understand. Can you please show what's the correct way? Also, can you please answer the other questions?

Comment: "Do not cast" implies that you simply leave out the typecast.

Comment: @Olaf [This answer about the `malloc()`-casting should help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @Olaf But this is from the docs. Plus, casting to something that matches the variable type already should not cause any issues. Anyway, I removed the " (int *)" part, and it still crashes with the same error

Comment: @androiddeveloper Docs have bugs, too. :)

Comment: You seem to have tagged wrong! That is one reason to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to allocate memory within a .rs file itself. You need to do all of your allocation within Java/C++, and then pass it into RS.

Comment: How come? It's a very basic thing to have... And how do you pass C/C++ allocated memory to it? Is it part of the heap, or part of the total memory of the device?

Comment: Allocating memory is time-consuming and not something we currently enable. You need to create memory using the Allocation class in either Java or C++ (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Allocation.html).

Comment: Sometimes I need to create a large chunk of memory. I can't even create an array in RS ? Why should I need to use JNI to do this (as the heap might not be enough and could cause OOM) ? I could initialize the RS and only later do the heavy computation. Would you please consider adding this? I also think that allocating the memory from outside of RS would be much more time consuming (for both the app and developer) than just do it inside RS

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible using `malloc()`; you are mis-reading the documentation.

It doesn't say the API *is* `malloc()`, it says it's *like* `malloc()`. The very same page you linked goes on to show this example code:

```
//Create an element manually and allocate memory for the int pointer
intPointer = Allocation.createSized(myRenderScript, Element.I32(myRenderScript), 2);
```

Which doesn't cast, but also doesn't look like it's C code.

Comment: That would be not C. Is the question wrongly tagged (which would explain casting `void *`)?

Comment: ok edited the tags to avoid confusion. How do I allocate stuff inside RS itself? For example, if I want to create a custom sized array, what should I do there? Also, Renderscript it based on C99 : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99